# bash: jstat: command not found

Tags: java, cassandra, jstat

I want to use the gc utility to analyse the garbage collection for my Cassandra database. But when I am running jstat command the output comes that bash:jstat: command not found. I searched and found that jstat is located in $JAVA_HOME/bin but I am not able to understand where is $JAVA_HOME/bin. I want to know how to start using jstat?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`jstat` is a tool which is available in jdk (development environment). If your application is using jre then only the tools under jre/bin will be available in your execution environment.
Make sure to use jdk as your execution environment to use `jstat` tool.

Comment: Also, make sure that the same user is trying to execute it. For example if the tomcat user has ran your java, try running; sudo -H -u tomcat ./jstat -gc <pid>

Answer (score 3):

To see `$JAVA_HOME` path, you have to run the following command:

> echo $JAVA_HOME

It will print java home directory path.

To run `jstat`, you have to go to `$JAVA_HOME/bin` path and run the following command:

> ./jstat -gc 29563

Note: `gc` is option (there are more options) and `29563` is java process ID. see [oracle document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jstat.html) for details.