# jstat: command not found

Tags: java, unix, solaris, solaris-10, jstat

I am working with Solaris 10 10/09 s10s_u8wos_08a SPARC.

When trying to use jstat utility, I am receiving the following prompts:

```
stires-web-a:/aaa/thirdParty/java/jdk1.8.0_101/bin->ls js* 
jsadebugd  jstack     jstat      jstatd 
stires-web-a:/aaa/thirdParty/java/jdk1.8.0_101/bin->jstat 
bash: jstat: command not found
```

Why is that happening?
I saw the question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30525862/bash-jstat-command-not-found), but didn't understand how to apply the solution.

Comment: What's the output from `echo $PATH`?

Comment: @AndrewHenle /usr/sbin:/usr/bin.
:)

Comment: So your `PATH` environment variable is `/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`, and `jstat` is located in `/aaa/thirdParty/java/jdk1.8.0_101/bin`?  What does that tell you?

Comment: @AndrewHenle That I need to add the path to JAVA_HOME, and I did: export JAVA_HOME=/aaa/thirdParty/java/jdk1.8.0_101  and   export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}       Now jstat doesn't do anything.  After I typed jstat 28510 250 7 I  see nothing and ps -ef | grep jstat gave me only the grep itself...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it appeared that there were 2 java installations on the machine and I have used the wrong one :(